# How to parse a text file to csv file using Perl

Tags: csv, perl

I am learning Perl and would like to parse a text file to csv file using Perl.  I have a loop that generates the following text file:

```
//This part is what outputs on the text file
for $row(@$data) {
  while(my($key,$value) = each(%$row)) {
    print "${key}=${value}, ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Text File Output:

```
name=Mary, id=231, age=38, weight=130, height=5.05, speed=26.233, time=30, 
time=25, name=Jose, age=30, id=638, weight=150, height=6.05, speed=20.233, 
age=40, weight=130, name=Mark, id=369, speed=40.555, height=5.07, time=30
```

CSV File Desired Output:

```
name,age,weight,height,speed,time
Mary,38,130,5.05,26.233,30, 
Jose,30,150,6.05,20.233,25, 
Mark,40,130,5.04,40.555,30
```

Any good feedback is welcome!

Comment: Yeah without spaces just wanted to show it clear in this post. Ok changed it!

Comment: To be much help, we'd really need to see `$data` too.

Comment: Also, it doesn't sound like you're **parsing** a CSV file. It looks like you're creating a CSV file.

Comment: I would like to create a CSV file from that text file.  Data is an array of hash which is similar to what zdim did.

Comment: @Bebe: So you're parsing a text file to a Perl array and producing a CSV file from that array. Is that correct? We really need to see the input file and the contents of `$data`.

Comment: @DaveCross I just updated the code block for what is in data, yes that would of help and noticed my sql query was odd for querying id.

Comment: @Bebe Also please check these modules https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::CSV and https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV

Comment: Yeah wanted this issue to be just parse from text file and not from the db but because there was an issue with HASH then was asked about how data looks like so went further to provide a snip.  If I go with DBD CSV then it will be another story.  I am good with @zdim answer below provided good info. I clean up a little too.

Comment: Thank you @zdim, your feedback helped me tons! So I was able to retrieve the data and output it into a csv file!

Comment: @Bebe Great, I'm very glad to hear that :).  I removed some of my early comments which are now outdated (as they were addressed by editing the question), to clean up, so that they don't distract.  Since I see that you implemented my last comment about code I edited your question to correct a few places; please review.

Comment: Ok @zdim I see your slice doc, I decided to remove that snip block so it stays with the issue posted.  Don't want to cause confusion for future readers.  Your throughly explanation below helped me solve the issue! Thank you again for editing your comments if someone has issues with hash ...

Comment: @Bebe OK, then I removed my comments referring to the previous version of the question, as they became unrelated to what's there now and so could only confuse a future reader.  Thank you for being responsive and fixing things (but always remember to be very careful with changes to a question as they can throw off and confuse).

Comment: Thank you @zdim! In deeed will do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key part here is how to manipulate your data so to extract what need be printed for each line.  Then you are best off using a module to produce valid CSV, and [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm#print) is very good.

A program using an array of small hashrefs, mimicking data in the question

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;

my @data = ( 
    { name => 'A', age => 1, weight => 10 },
    { name => 'B', age => 2, weight => 20 },
);
    
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2 });

my $outfile = 'test.csv';
open my $ofh, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";

# Header, also used below for order of values for fields 
my @hdr = qw(name age weight);
$csv->say($ofh, \@hdr);

foreach my $href (@data) {
    $csv->say($ofh, [ @{$href}{@hdr} ]); 
}
```

The values from hashrefs in a desired order are extracted using a hashref [slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices) `@{$href}{@hdr}`, what is in general

```
@{ expression returning hash reference } { list of keys }
```

This returns a list of values for the given list of keys, from the hashref that the expression in the block `{}` must return.  That is then used to build an arrayref (an anonymous array here, using `[]`), what the module's [`say` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm#say) needs in order to make and print a string of comma-separated-values<sup>†</sup> from that list of values.

Note a block that evaluates to a hash reference, used instead of a *hash name* that is used for a slice of a *hash*.  This is a general [rule](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Block) that

> Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a BLOCK returning a reference of the correct type.

Some further comments

- Look over the supported constructor's attributes; there are many goodies
- For very simple data you can simply join fields with a comma and print

  ```
  say $ofh join ',', @{$href}{@hdr};
  ```

  But it is far safer to use a module to construct a valid CSV record.  With the right choice of attributes in the constructor it can handle whatever is legal to embed in fields (some of what can take quite a bit of work to do correctly by hand) *and* it calls things which aren't
- I list column names explicitly. Instead, you can fetch the `keys` and then `sort` in a desired order, but this will again need a hard-coded list for sorting

The program creates the file `test.csv` and prints to it the expected header and data lines.

---

<sup>†</sup> But separating those "values" with commas may involve a whole lot more than merely what the acronym for the "CSV *format*" stands for. A variety of things may come between those commas, including commas, newlines, and whatnot. This is why one is best advised to always use a library.  Seeing constructor's options is informative.

---

*The following commentary referred to the initial question. In the meanwhile the problems this addresses were corrected in OP's code and the question updated.  I'm still leaving this text for some general comments that can be useful.*

As for the code in the question and its output, there is almost certainly an issue with how the data is processed to produce `@data`, judged by the presence of *keys* `HASH(address)` in the output.

That string `HASH(0x...)` is output when one prints a variable which is a hash reference (what cannot show any of hash's content). Perl handles such a print by *[stringifying](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary#stringification)* (producing a printable string out of something which is more complex) the reference in that way.

There is no good reason to have a hash reference for a hash key.  So I'd suggest that you review your data and its processing and see how that comes about.  (Or briefly show this, or post another question with it if it isn't feasible to add that to this one.)

One measure you can use to bypass that is to only use a list of keys that you know are valid, like I show above; however, then you may be leaving some outright error unhandled.  So I'd rather suggest to find what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you @zdim, yes its supposed to be in caps that hash and added those commas, will try your sample!

Comment: Text::CSV is the only way to parse that text file to csv? I was thinking of writing a perl script that takes that text file and parse it to csv with few line of code :)

Comment: @Bebe  I assume that you somehow "parse" (process) some file to obtain `@data`.  Then this need be used to get values for the output (`Mary`, `38`, `130`, ... etc); for this I use `@{$href}{@hdr}`.  Once you have that then you can print it to a file, with a comma between values.  I use (and suggest) `Text::CSV` for this, to print CSV-style output (CSV stands for Comma-Separated-Values).  But for simple data you can do it manually (as shown in a comment)

Comment: @Bebe  See the `@data` I made up -- that's how an array with hash-references should look.  If you have a `HASH(....) => ` in the output that means that there is a key  which itself is a hash-reference.  I cannot tell why that is there but it is almost certainly an error of some kind. Investigate the original data (in the file from which it is obtained) and how it is processed to get your `@data` (so, how is that file "parsed" to build `@data` from it).

Comment: @Bebe Thank you for clarifying and editing that `hash(...)` thing!  I added  commentary on that to the end of the answer

Comment: Thank @zdim I updated the code a little since I want to fix the issue of HASH which was coming from how i query id in sql for the data so I posted it.  I tried your method and I am getting black csv.  I will continue looking into it...

Comment: @Bebe Alright, by what I see in your update the `HASH(...)` problem is gone! You say "_I am getting black csv_"  (you mean getting it _back_?) -- that was what you asked for, so all is good now, yes?

Comment: @Bebe I'm glad that this helped :)  Let me know if questions come up